# Why do my photos have such poor quality?

Tags: image-quality, sony

I've been using my camera Sony DSC HX100v for years. Lately, some photos have really poor quality (photos taken before and after on the same day look fine). I usually use automatic mode only, so I am wondering if that is a sign for my camera not working properly anymore?

[image]

*Edit*

Here's the details from exif.regex.info:

EXIF — this group of metadata is encoded in 152 bytes (0.1k)

> Exposure Time 1/2000
> F Number  5.60
> Exposure Program  Program AE
> ISO   3,200 Sensitivity Type
> Recommended Exposure Index
> Recommended Exposure Index    3,200
> Exif Version  0230
> Components Configuration  Y, Cb, Cr, -
> Compressed Bits Per Pixel 2
> Brightness Value  9.73984375
> Exif Image Size   4,608 × 3,456
> Exposure Compensation 0
> Max Aperture Value    2.8
> Metering Mode Multi-segment
> Light Source  Unknown
> Flash Off, Did not fire
> Focal Length  4.8 mm
> Contrast  Normal
> Exposure Mode Auto
> Maker Note Sony   (12,324 bytes binary data)
> User Comment
> Flashpix Version  0100
> Color Space   sRGB
> Interoperability Index    R98 - DCF basic file (sRGB)
> Interoperability Version  0100
> File Source   Digital Camera
> Scene Type    Directly photographed
> Custom Rendered   Normal
> White Balance Auto
> Digital Zoom Ratio    1
> Scene Capture Type    Standard
> Saturation    Normal
> Sharpness Normal
> Lens Info 4.8-144mm f/2.8-5.6
> Print Image Matching  (28 bytes binary data)
> Compression   JPEG (old-style)
> Image Description
> Make  SONY
> Camera Model Name DSC-HX100V
> Orientation   Horizontal (normal)
> Resolution    72 pixels/inch
> Thumbnail Length  11,261
> Y Cb Cr Positioning   Co-sited
> Exif Image Width  1,440
> Exif Image Height 1,080
> Thumbnail Image   (11,261 bytes binary data)

Comment: Is this image resized for posting here? If not, perhaps it was taken **while in video mode**? From the **manual**, *"Shooting still images while recording a movie ... The image size of still images is fixed to [16:9 (3M)]. If the movie image size is set to [MP4 3M], the still image size is fixed to [4:3 (2M)].*" The image is consistent with that of a very low pixel resolution.

Comment: @user10216038 Even 2Mp (1600x1200) images look better than that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the issue is explained by the first four lines of the EXIF information:

> Exposure Time 1/2000
> F Number 5.60
> Exposure Program Program AE
> ISO 3,200 Sensitivity Type

For this particular photo you used the [P, or Program, mode of your camera](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/43703/9161).
The actual behaviour varies between cameras, but the baseline is that you let the camera decide what shutter speed (exposure time), aperture (F number) and sensor sensitivity (ISO) to use to get a properly exposed photo (see [this previous question on their relation to each other](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/6598/9161)).

The camera chose to use a very short exposure time, which required a higher sensor sensitivity (an ISO of 3200).
A higher ISO often correlates to more noise in the photo, which the camera tries to correct with noise reduction technology.

As your camera is quite old, the sensor is not very developed, high ISO results in relatively high noise, which in turn requires a lot of correction.

This correction is probably causing the "really poor quality".
I don't think this is a sign of camera failure, just a sub-optimal choice of exposure settings.

To prevent this in the future try to limit the maximum ISO the camera can choose, especially when you know you will be shooting in broad daylight.
The camera will then choose a longer exposure time, requiring a lower ISO and less noise reduction.

Answer (score 4):

It's both the gear *and* your (lack of) technique.

First off, your camera is a 10-year-old model superzoom bridge camera that uses a small 1/2.3"-format sensor.  The smudging and color blocks you see when you magnify your file are basically due to having such a high ISO (3200) setting with such a small/old sensor. You probably don't want to go much above ISO 800 unless there's a good reason.  If you have the image quality set to higher compression on the JPEGs that might be exacerbating the issue.

But your technique of simply putting the camera on an automated exposure mode (programmable auto) and handholding are also at fault.  Your camera's auto-exposure system chose a very high ISO (3200) and shutter speed (1/2000s) combination possibly assuming you'd be using the superzoom lens at its supertelephoto end, or as if it were set for a low-light (e.g., night time) scene.  If you're using [a scene mode](https://helpguide.sony.net/gbmig/42755111/v1/eng/contents/06/02/03/03.html), you might want to check that it's on landscape for landscape shots like this.

And your camera has the PSAM modes and a tripole mount hole.  You can put the camera on a tripod to hold it steady, and explicitly set the camera to use a much slower shutter speed and ISO, while still using a smaller aperture for deep depth of field without getting any camera shake blur from handholding.

See also:

- [What is the "exposure triangle"?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6598/what-is-the-exposure-triangle)
- [Why are my photos not crisp?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50006/why-are-my-photos-not-crisp)

Comment: The camera chose f/5.6 for the photo.  The lens probably doesn't go much slower than this because diffraction will be too severe with the small sensor.  My Nikon P900 with the same size sensor and number of pixels will not go past f/9.5